# Gogle app script to give access to my files only for my youtube memberships

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-api, google-sheets-api

Newbie here guys i was looking Gogle app script services but i cant find a way to aproach it at the moment, anyone knows if its possible? and if so, could you guide me in the right way?

My idea is to have snippet codes working with some google sheets where will be forms where only my youtube memberships can access and interact with it (ex. form for calculate your weight) BUT this users cant see the code behind it, like any app.

Maybe there is another external app for aproach that? i dont know actually

Answer (score 1):

You can manually share the sheet with who ever you want.

Anyone with access to a sheet can see scripts

There is no way of knowing who has subscribed to a YouTube channel

I think what I am saying is what you want to do can't be done with app script

Comment: yeah but im looking for an automated process

Comment: There isnt one really as there is no way to list who has subscribed to your youtube channel.